# I have a question about how a check was written

Tags: banking, check

I have a check for $2500.00 written to me. The longhand is written "twenty-five hundred" instead of the standard "two thousand five hundred". Will the banks accept the check?

Comment: I've never had a problem with that.

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: If the "twenty-" part is scrunched together on the left side of the check, then maybe...

Comment: It depends on country regulations as well as common practise. It can even be written as two five zero zero.

Answer (score 6):

Both phrasings are idiomatically correct, and the banking system doesn't care which is used as long as it ***is*** correct.

Answer (score -1):

Nobody cares about what's written there if you deposit it online or on a machine, I tested it once by writing "*nothing*" in the text field. Even a clerk will probably not even look there.

Only if there are complaints, a human will really look at the check, and humans will understand that term. No issue to be expected.

Comment: The fact that it is not being checked doesn't mean it is not invalid. One of the banks I use never checks, the other - always checks and I had a check rejected for much less. That said, if a check that's invalid gets disputed - it will be bounced by default and you won't have any remedy.

Comment: I am quite sure that _twenty-five-hundred_ is valid too. It is so common, I guess half of Americans wouldn't even know that _two-thousand-five-hundred_ exists and is the proper form.

Comment: Yes, it's valid, but the premise of your answer was that it doesn't matter - and I disagree with that.

Comment: I have had the experience of cashing a check for which the numerical version and the textual version of the amount did not match. The bank went with the textual version. Therefore, in my experience, what is written there *does* matter.